# Why doesn't the HTML maxlength and minlenght attribute work in chrome?

Tags: html

**I know it's done with javascript but I'm wondering why it's not working**

`<input type="number" min="0" max=3" name="cw" id="cw">`

or

`<input type="number" minlength="0" maxlength="3" name="cw" id="cw">`

Comment: It should work. CHeck it here. `https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_max.asp`.
Or you past your whole code to see what is missing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [mre] to help us reproduce your issue